# Correctness of implicit lifting

Tags: haskell, types

Imagine that I have a value that is generic over the monad:

```
m :: (Monad m) => m A  -- 'A' is some concrete type
```

Now let's say that I specialize this value to a concrete monad transformer stack in two separate ways:

```
m1 :: T M A
m1 = m

m2 :: T M A
m2 = lift m
```

... where `M` and `T M` are monads, and `T` is a monad transformer:

```
instance Monad M where ...
instance (Monad m) => Monad (T m) where ...
instance MonadTrans T where ...
```

... and those instances obey the monad laws and monad transformer laws.

Can we deduce that:

```
m1 = m2
```

... knowing nothing about `m` other than its type?

This is just a long-winded way of asking if `lift m` is a valid substitution for `m`, assuming that both type-check.  It is a little bit difficult to phrase the question because it requires `m` type-checking as two separate monads before and after the substitution.  As far as I can tell, the only way such a substitution would type-check is if `m` is generic over the monad.

My vague intuition is that the substitution should always be correct, but I'm not sure that my intuition is correct, or how to prove it if it is correct.

Answer (score 9):

If `m :: Monad m => m A`, then `m` must be equivalent to `return x` for some `x :: A`, because the only ways you have to get anything `:: m x` are `return` and `(>>=)`. But in order to use `(>>=)` you must be able to produce some `m y`, which you can either do with `return` or with another application of `(>>=)`. Either way you have to use `return` eventually, and the monad laws guarantee that the whole expression will be equivalent to `return x`.

(If `m` is completely polymorphic over the monad, then you must able to use it at `m ~ Identity`, so it can't use any fancy monad tricks, unless you pass it an argument. This sort of trick is used e.g. [here](http://comonad.com/reader/2011/searching-infinity/) and [here](http://okmij.org/ftp/Computation/lem.html).)

Given that `m = return x`, we know by the monad transformer laws (`lift . return = return`) that `lift m = m`.

Of course, this is only true for this particular type. If you have, say, `m :: MonadState S m => m A`, then `m` could easily be different from `lift m` -- for example, with a type like `StateT A (State A) A`, `get` and `lift get` will be different.

(And of course all of this is ignoring ⊥. Then again, if you don't, most monads don't obey the laws anyway.)

Comment: this is "proof by parametricity" and can be expressed formally.  Your argument is good enough though.

Comment: Sure, this is just a sketch. By the way, I should note that I was ignoring `fail`. In the presence of `fail`, `m` and `lift m` can behave differently. (Not that there any `fail` laws, as such... But with actual monad transformers in `mtl` you can make a counterexample.)

Comment: I am specifically interested in the explanation of the parametricity treatment, the reason being that I have a more sophisticated problem in my mind regarding pipes.  If you or @PhilipJF explains that I will accept this answer.

Comment: @GabrielGonzalez shachaf beat me by a 30 seconds, but what's your response to my answer? I'd also be interested in seeing someone more experienced construct a proof, or respond to what I've attempted so I can learn something from all this too

Comment: @jberryman Your answer is very similar to my , which is why I up voted it, but I was looking for something really elegant and general because I want to generalize this line of reasoning to pipes.

Comment: @GabrielGonzalez thanks for responding; it seemed like my answer was being ignored despite AFAICT answering your question thoroughly (why the hell do I care?). In any case, you can make my solution as general as you like (i.e. generalize to other classes beyond Monad) by enumerating the possible values according to the methods offered by your class (my `mA` and mB` below) and then going through the same motions with the laws you've got, no? Anyway, good luck with your problem!

Comment: @jberryman Sorry for the delayed response.  Yeah, I think you are right about enumerating methods.  I was just hoping there was an elegant answer to this.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is a sloppy [inductive proof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_induction) that your `m` is equivalent to `lift m`.

I think we have to try to prove something about `m` (or rather, about all possible values of type `(Monad m) => m A`). If we consider `Monad` as consisting of bind and return only, and ignore bottom and `fail` then your `m` must at the top level be one of:

```
mA = return (x)
mB = (mX >>= f)
```

For `mA` the two forms of `m` are equivalent by the monad transformer law:

```
lift (return (x)) = return (x)
```

That's the base case. Then we're left with the second transformer law to reason about `mB`:

```
lift (mX >>= f) = lift mX >>= (lift . f)
```

and where we'd like to prove that that our `mB` is equal to that expansion:

```
mX >>= f = lift mX >>= (lift . f)
```

we assume that the left side of bind is equivalent (`mX = lift mX`) since that's our inductive hypothesis (right?).

So then we're left to prove `f =  lift . f` by figuring out what `f` has to look like:

```
f :: a -> m b
f = \a -> (one of our forms mA or mB)
```

and `lift . f` looks like:

```
f = \a -> lift (one of our forms mA or mB)
```

Which leaves us back with our hypothesis:

```
m = lift m
```